# JQuery Bootgrid, search doesn't find formatted columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-bootgrid

I have a JQuery Bootgrid with two formatters needed to format correctly a date and euro values columns (in the rows I store the date as string in the format YYYYMMDD to get the column ordered correctly if the user choose to order that column, while the table output is in the date format DD/MM/YYYY. Also, I simply add the € symbol to the euro output values.

Put very simply, the default search feature of JQuery Bootgrid searches the original values, not the formatted ones, while I surely need to give to the user the ability to search the formatted values. If you have a solution or even a workaround please help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you're working off a data source, you could always normalize the search from the backend (i.e. the json provider).

Enhancing an existing table - well, Grid.prototype.search is the function.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem, where the search was looking at the original data rather than the formatted data, but needed the original data for sorting.

What I did was set `data-searchable="false"` on the formatted column, and then added a new column with the date already formatted by myself. This new column was then set to `data-visible="false"`. The table structure was something along the lines of:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="date" data-formatter="dateNoTimeFormat" data-searchable="false">Report Date</th>
            <th data-column-id="formattedDate" data-visible="false"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $reportDate; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($reportDate)); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

By default, the bootgrid search doesn't include the hidden columns, so the source also needs modifying slightly. There is a function `containsPhrase(row)` in `jquery.bootgrid.js` (line 172 in v1.3.1) which has an `if` statement reading:

```
if (column.searchable && column.visible &&
    column.converter.to(row[column.id]).search(searchPattern) > -1)
{
    return true;
}
```

The `&& column.visible` needs removing from the code, meaning the search will also look at columns set to be hidden.

Comment: Thank you! I solved time ago using another approach, now I don't remember how. :)

Comment: @1Garrett2010 no problem, I'd been looking for a while and couldn't find anything so thought I'd put it there to help anyone else in the future! :)